# Is it possible to make a website in C++ using FastCGI Libraries?

Tags: c++, fastcgi

Is it possible that you could make a website entirely in C++ using the FastCGI libraries? If so, are there any examples, or any thing I can read that I can learn more from?

Comment: I would guess so. It says you can on their [page](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/). As for examples, [just take a look at the link they provide on their site](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/?q=node/3).

Comment: Of course you can provide FastCGI modules using c++. Quesiton is, if you really want to do so?

Comment: Also, [this is the second result](http://chriswu.me/blog/writing-hello-world-in-fcgi-with-c-plus-plus/) of googling for **fast CGI C++ example**...

Comment: While it is certainly possible to "implement a website" in *any* language, including C++, I would cordially submit that "C++ might be overkill."  There are lots of interpreted languages that are more-or-less specifically designed to create web pages, such that it is probably easier and faster to do the job in one of those.

Comment: @nonsensickle I did find that example before, but I was looking for an example that has multiple pages, or an "actual site" in a real-life use.

Comment: @nonsensickle Also those are just servers that support fastcgi, not actual examples? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but not recommended unless you need something very specific. I'd only use C++ for a web app if I was severely RAM-constrained or if I worked at something that requires VERY HIGH request per seconds.

Take in consideration that nowadays high level languages such as Python or C# .NET has much better web tools and frameworks than C++, and its standard libraries work very well. **And you don't have to worry about memory management!**

If you still want to continue with this, here you have a basic guide which covers beginner's aspects. It covers from preparing environment, writing a sample `Hello world` web page, and setting up Nginx for running it:

http://chriswu.me/blog/writing-hello-world-in-fcgi-with-c-plus-plus/

Comment: you dont have to worry about memory managment in C++ either, if you know what you are doing, you will let the RAII handle it for you(smart pointers anyone?). Its long dead argument

Comment: Cheers :) And yah I'm just doing it to learn more, not for anything serious.

Comment: Yes, i think that you're right if we assume that someone will **only** pick up c++ for web development **only** if him knows what is doing, but it can not be the case.